# Dotnetopenauth : validate a token without catching ProtocolFaultResponseException

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

I'm implementing a service that look for the presence (an validity) of a OAuth2 token. I do this using the following code

```
try
{
    token = server.GetAccessToken();

    //do token expiration validation and scope verifications

}
catch (ProtocolFaultResponseException ex)
{
    //Process Exception
}
```

Is there a better way than catching an exception to test the presence of the token (something like TryGetAccessToken) ?

Thanks